# How to unmount all other drives at boot

Tags: linux, boot, external-hdd

So, I got an Ubuntu running from an external drive, which I am using at different laptops. I got one with Windows, and one with a Lubuntu (this laptop has only got 16 gb internal storage). What I am afraid of, that Ubuntu will write to one of my other systems, and make them unusable. I am trying to find a way to automatically unmount all other drives that the system detects. Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just not mount them on boot by removing them from your `/etc/fstab`?

Comment: Yes, that would be good, but what if I boot it from a different computer? I would need to remove them separetly. I am looking for a global solution.